# How to compare values between rows and find the average of responses?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, subquery

I have a MySQL table of user responses to yes/no poll questions. Looks kinda like this:

```
| user_id    | poll_id  | response  |
|------------|----------|-----------|
|    111     |    1     |   'yes'   |
|    111     |    2     |   'no'    |
|    111     |    3     |   'no'    |
|    222     |    1     |   'yes'   |
|    222     |    2     |   'yes'   |
|    222     |    3     |   'yes'   |
|    333     |    1     |   'no'    |
|    333     |    2     |   'no'    |
|    333     |    3     |   'no'    |
```

I'd like to compute the similarity between each user's responses and every other user's responses. So, user 111 and user 222 are 0.333 similar (because they have 1 out of 3 same responses), and user 111 and user 333 are 0.666 similar (because they have 2 out of 3 same responses).

I've written a query that will give me the number of same responses for two specified users:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS same_count 
FROM    (
            SELECT  response 
            FROM    results 
            WHERE   user_id = 111
        ) AS t1
    ,   (
            SELECT  response 
            FROM    results 
            WHERE   user_id = 222
        ) AS t2 
WHERE   t1.response = t2.response
```

Now I'm trying to figure out a way to get that info for all users, to produce results like this:

```
| user_1  |  user_2  |  same_count  |
|---------|----------|--------------|
|  111    |   222    |    0.333     |
|  111    |   333    |    0.666     |
|  222    |   111    |    0.333     |
|  222    |   333    |    0         |
|  333    |   111    |    0.666     |
|  333    |   222    |    0         |
```

Or, if possible, without the redundant info:

```
| user_1  |  user_2  |  same_count  |
|---------|----------|--------------|
|  111    |   222    |    0.333     |
|  111    |   333    |    0.666     |
|  222    |   333    |    0         |
```

My gut tells me there's a way to do this as a single monstrous MySQL query, without having to result to performing a bunch of queries via loops in PHP.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you really want to have a table whose size is the square of the user table ? With computations and size in a square function of a table's size you may have a problem if you plan to have a lot of users.

Answer (score 3):

You have to perform a full outer join with the same table using the columns *poll_id* and *user_id*. The results will show twice and in order to avoid that we need to specify the condition in such a way that only the *alias1* table's `user_id` values that are lesser than the *alias2* table's `user_id` values alone are included in the result set.

[**Click here to view the demo in SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bc770/27)

*Script*:

```
CREATE TABLE poll
(
    user_id     INT         NOT NULL
  , poll_id     INT         NOT NULL
  , response    VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL  
);

INSERT INTO poll (user_id, poll_id, response) VALUES
   (111, 1, 'yes'),
   (111, 2, 'no'),
   (111, 3, 'no'),
   (222, 1, 'yes'),
   (222, 2, 'yes'),
   (222, 3, 'yes'),
   (333, 1, 'no'),
   (333, 2, 'no'),
   (333, 3, 'no');

SELECT      p1.user_id AS user_1
        ,   p2.user_id AS user_2, 
            AVG(CASE 
                    WHEN p1.response = p2.response THEN 1 
                    ELSE 0 
                END) Average_Response
FROM        poll p1
,           poll p2 
WHERE       p1.poll_id = p2.poll_id 
AND         p1.user_id < p2.user_id
GROUP BY    p1.user_id
        ,   p2.user_id;
```

*Output*:

```
USER_1 USER_2 AVERAGE_RESPONSE
------ ------ ----------------
111     222      0.3333
111     333      0.6667
222     333      0
```

Answer (score 1):

This should get you the desired result:

```
SELECT
  t1.user_id AS user_1,
  t2.user_id AS user_2,
  SUM(CASE WHEN t1.response = t2.response THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(1)
    AS same_count
FROM t t1
JOIN t t2 ON ( t2.user_id > t1.user_id AND t2.poll_id = t1.poll_id )
GROUP BY t1.user_id, t2.user_id
ORDER BY user_1, user_2
```

My test-results:

```
111 222 0.333333333333333
111 333 0.666666666666667
222 333 0
```

---

The `CASE` part could be written easier in MySQL as (`t1.response = t2.response`), my version will also work with other types databases.
This part does the main trick by counting all those entries that match, and dividing the count by the number of entries.

The `t2.user_id > t1.user_id` will remove the duplicates (111 - 222, 222 - 111).